# How to load a file in PyQt4?

Tags: python, image, pyqt4

everyone! I am currently attempting to make a program that will load/display images. So far, I have successfully created a button with the ability to browse and select your file. However, I do not know what to do after that. My goal for this, is to at least successfully load and display an image. I am still very new to programming, but am willing to learn! Thank you, so much!

Below, is the code I have created. I really just need to help as to what I am supposed to do next. I am lost as to what functions I am supposed to write next. Thanks!

```
__author__ = 'Jay'

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)
        self.setWindowTitle('Laser Scan')
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Laser.png'))
        self.home()

        self.show()

    def home(self):
        btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Select File...", self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.file_open)
        btn.resize(100, 25)
        btn.move(0, 10)


        self.show()

    def file_open(self):
        name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File')
        file = open(name, 'r')

def run():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Showing an image from a file is pretty easy in Qt.  You just need to find the right widget.  In this case I suggest you use a `QLabel`.  This can display a `QPixmap` and that includes the code necessary to construct from a file:

```
def file_open(self):
    name = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open File')
    qp = QtGui.QPixmap(name)
    self.ql = QtGui.QLabel(None)
    self.ql.setPixmap(qp)
    self.ql.move(200,200)
    self.ql.show()
```

Note the way that I assign the `QLabel` to an instance variable `self.ql` here: because it is a top-level window, it is not parented in the `QObject` hierarchy and so it will immediately be garbage collected if we don't hold on to a reference to it.  In any case, we'll want that reference in the future if we intend to do anything with the new widget.

However, your code hints that you want to show the image inside the top level window you have already constructed.  That is not particularly hard: you can just add it to the parent window like the button.  However, you will then need to lay out this window more dynamically.  For example, a `QVBoxLayout` might be appropriate here.

Comment: Thank you, @strubbly! I really appreciate the help and detailed description on how this works! I honestly love this. Once again, thanks! You have a great day, man!